# Adding new columns to Forecast Type don't apear in the page layout

Tags: table, forecast

When I add a new field to the forecast selected columns it doesn't seem to appear on the forecast layout. Does anyone know how to fix it ?

[image]
[image]

most of the fields are from the opportunity tab. The Stage field is a master pick list to the sub stage I don't know if it has anything to do with that because they are both pick lists.

Comment: did u check the field level permissions of the sub stage field to see if the user has access to it ?

Comment: yes i did everyone has access to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might have missed to Save the Forecast Settings after adding the column.

Once you add the field to the selected column, you have to

- click OK in that forecast type config page and
- click Save in the forecast settings page